# Why does firefox keep highlighting my drop down menu links? Possibly CSS/JQuery related

Tags: jquery, css

Every time I click the div that activates/drops down my drop down menu the links are highlighted:

[image]

Quite annoying. It's either a CSS or JQuery issue.. I have a .postHolder class that holds each  post that is posted on the page. Now if I click any where on the screen to close the menu then click on the menu open button again the issue is gone. If I go to the next post and try the issue is there until I click off then click on again.

If I refresh the browser the issue is back, starting on the first post. This is quite confusing as it's not happening in any of my other browsers.

Here is the CSS for the menu:

```
.postMenu {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:white !important;
    border:1px solid $main-background-color;
    height:163px;
    width:170px;
    top:18px;
    right:2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    color:gray;
    z-index:3000;

        li {

        font-size:12px;
        height:33px;
        background-color:white !important;

            a span {
                float:left;
                width:160px;
                height:33px;
                line-height:33px;
                padding-left:10px;
                color:gray;

                  &:hover {
                    background-color:#4D90FE !important;
                    color:white;
                    //  #DD4B39,#D14836
                    }
            }

            &:hover {
            background-color:#4D90FE;
            color:white;

            }
        }

        .deletePost {
            //position:relative;
            padding-top:0px !important;
            padding-left:0px !important;
            height:39px;
            width:170px;
            text-align:center;
            padding-bottom:7px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #d9d9d9;

                a {

                    span {
                    float:left;
                    padding-left:0px !important;                            
                        height:46px !important;
                        width:170px !important;
                        line-height:46px;
                    }
                }

                a span:hover {
                    background-color:#DD4B39 !important;
                    color:white;
                //  #DD4B39,#D14836
                }
        }

        .reportAbuse {
            border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;

                a span:hover {
                    background-color:gray !important;;
                }

        }

}
```

The JQuery incase this is JQuery related:

```
    $(".microposts").on("click", ".micropostOptions", function() {
        var postMenu = $(this).find('.postMenu');

        if(postMenu.is(':hidden') ){
            $('.postMenu').hide();
            $('.micropostOptions').removeClass("postMenuHoverState");
            postMenu.show();
            $(this).hide().addClass('postMenuHoverState').show(60);

        }else{
            postMenu.hide();
            $(this).removeClass("postMenuHoverState");
        }

    $(document.body).click(function(e) {
        var clickedElement = $(e.target);
        if(clickedElement.is('.micropostOptions:visible')) {
            return;
        }
        $('.postMenu').hide();
        $('.micropostOptions').removeClass("postMenuHoverState");
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
   <nav class="micropostOptions">
         <ul class="postMenu">
           <li class="deletePost"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Delete post"), m, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => m.content, :class => "message_delete" %>
           </li>
           <li class="disableCommenting"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Pause commenting"), "2" %></li>
           <li class="blockCommenter"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Block commenter"), "3" %></li>
           <li class="openInNewWindow"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Open in new window"), "4" %></li>
           <li class="reportAbuse"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Report abuse"), "5" %></li>
         </ul>  
       </nav>
```

Kind regards

Comment: If you link us to a site, we can use Firebug to inspect it and tell you exactly where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I would but the website is on a local server.

Comment: Well, in the spirit of "Teach a man to fish", you should install the Firebug add-on for Firefox, then right click on the highlighted text and select "Inspect Element with Firebug" - this will show you only the CSS that's being applied to the element you clicked.

Comment: I use firebug, maybe not as good as I should be. I'll give that a try. I couldn't see anything suspicious when I originally checked.

Comment: The hovering wasn't the issue as I thought. Seeing as this menu worked in every other browser correctly I knew that wasn't the issue. I even commented out all hovering and the issue still occurred. It's like someone took the cursor and literally highlighted the links in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue for now. Well masked it.

```
span::-moz-selection {
    background: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
&:hover {
    background-color:#4D90FE;
```

Assuming that the links in your dropdown list are also in `<li>` this style is being inherited.

Answer (score 2):

Your css is setting a background color on hover:

```
    &:hover {
    background-color:#4D90FE;
    color:white;
    }
```

The

```
a span {
color:gray;
}
```

overrides the color you set for `:hover` and sets it to gray.

Comment: Hmm, It all seems fine in the other browsers. Not sure what to do here. The first background shows up red then the next links show up light blue and the last gray. That's how I've set the highlighting and it works every where else.

Comment: Your jQuery is also adding and removing a class called `postMenuHoverState`, what does this CSS look like?  All browsers seem to treat CSS property inheritance differently - Firefox at times is smart enough to figure out the implied inheritance while other browsers take the literal form (which can be good for properly setting your css inheritance)

Comment: postMenuHoverstate is some setting for the button that is clicked to drop down the menu. I notice if I click any where on screen or on the button again the highlighted links un-highlight just before the box closes. it's like something is highlighting those links before the menu opens as I click on the button to open the menu.

Comment: Perhaps you have a reset.css or another parent css setting the select state specific to the browser at hand?  Using the HTML5 Boilerplate, it sets the select colors by default and to pink at that :)